Real time correlation function from inverse Fourier/Laplace transform
In a diffusive system described by Maxwell-Cattaneo equation $$\tau \partial_t^2 n+\partial_t n- D \nabla^2 n=0,$$ which reduces to simple diffusion at $\tau=0$, I have calculated the correlation function $G_{nn}(\omega,k)$ and its correction due to the nonlinear effects: $D\equiv D_0+ D' n + \cdots$.
My result is formally written as $$G_{nn}(\omega,k)=G^{(0)}_{nn}(\omega,k)+\delta G_{nn}(\omega,k).$$ For the leading part, I can use the contour techniques to find $G^{(0)}_{nn}(t,k)$. But the situation is more complicated for $\delta G_{nn}$.
In the limit $\tau D k^2\gg1$ the expression is slightly simpler and is as follows
$$\delta G_{nn}(t,k)= (T \chi)D'^2\,k^4\,(\tau D k^2)^{1/2}\int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(D k^2- i \omega-\tau \omega^2)^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{D k^2- i \omega(2- i \tau \omega)}}e^{- i \omega t}.$$
Branch point singularities are a result of nonlinear interactions.
The way I perform this integral is as follows
$\bullet$ First setting $\omega= i s$, thus converting the inverse Fourier integral to an inverse Laplace integral.
.
$\bullet$ Performing the Inverse-Laplace transform on the two factors of the integrand, separately:
$$f(t,k)\equiv\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{\sqrt{(s-s_1)(s-s_2)}}]=e^{\frac{1}{2}(s_1+s_2)t} J_0\big(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-(s_1-s_2)^2}\big)$$
$$g(t,k)\equiv\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{\big((s-s_3)(s-s_4)\big)^2}]=\frac{2 e^{s_4 t}-2 e^{s_3 t}}{(s_3-s_4)^2}+t\frac{ e^{s_4 t}+ e^{s_3 t}}{(s_3-s_4)^2}$$
where $J_0$ is a Bessel function.
$\bullet$ In the final step, I would try to find the convolution of the above two functions.
$$\delta G_{nn}(t,k) \sim \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt' f(t',k)g(t-t',k)$$
After applying the limits and re-scalings, the convolution is given by the following expression in my Mathematica code

Unfortunately, Mathematica cannot compute it. When I expand $Cos$ into a series, Mathematica can perform the convolution for each term in the expansion. However, I do not see any kind of convergence by increasing the number of terms.
Considering the above points, any comments or suggestions that can help in computing $\delta G_{nn}(t,k)$ would be greatly appreciated.
COMMENT: In response to @LPZ's answer, I added the following two plots:

This shows the numerical results for the inverse Fourier integral with $Dk^2=2$ and $\tau=2$. The following figure shows the results found by @LPZ: The function grows oscillatingly, but at very small t it matches the numerical results.

are you sure about the extra $2$ in the square root?

@LPZ Yes! As I mentioned, the square root expression gives the location of branch points, which are in fact the pinch singularities of a loop integral. These don’t coincide with the free theory poles. The latter can be found from the denominator of the first expression in the integrand.  In analogy with scalar QFT, in QFT, the first denominator gives $p^2=m^2$, while the square root expression gives the threshold singularity $p^2=(2m)^2$.

If there is a closed form result is analytic, probably the best option is to directly compute the Laplace transform. I do not think that going first in time domain and then computing the convolution product is a good strategy.
I did not redo your calculation, but you probably already used $Dk^2\tau\gg1$ to simplify your formulas. The approximation error is probably not uniform in $\omega$, and your integral is already too precise. You can further simplify it at leading order.
Let $s_1,s_2$ be the roots of:
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= Dk^2+2s+\tau s^2=0\\
s &= \frac{-1+\sqrt{1-Dk^2\tau}}\tau\\
&= \pm i\frac{\sqrt{Dk^2\tau}}\tau-\frac1\tau
\end{align}
$$
and $s_3,s_4$ the roots of:
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= Dk^2+s+\tau s^2=0\\
s &= \frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4Dk^2\tau}}{2\tau}\\
&\sim \pm i\frac{\sqrt{Dk^2\tau}}\tau-\frac2\tau
\end{align}
$$
In this limit, there is a separation of scales between the size $\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}$ and the distance between the poles and branch points $1/\tau$. Therefore the Green's function does not converge uniformly, and you get different limiting functions depending on the scaling.
In frequency space, focusing only on the term:
$$
\hat G=\frac1{(Dk^2+s+\tau s^2)^2\sqrt{Dk^2+2s+\tau s^2}}
$$
You have for $\omega$ of order $1/\tau$:
$$
\hat G=\frac1{(Dk^2)^{5/2}}
$$
For $\omega$ of order $\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}$:
$$
\hat G=\frac1{(Dk^2+\tau s^2)^{5/2}}
$$
For $\omega$ of order $Dk^2$:
$$
\hat G=\frac1{(\tau\omega^2)^{5/2}}
$$
Remember that under the previous assumptions, $1/\tau \ll \sqrt{Dk^2/\tau} \ll Dk^2$. There is also another regime which dissociates the branch points from the pole is to take $\omega$ of order $1/\tau$ about one of the branch cuts:
$$
\hat G=\frac1{((s-s_1-1/\tau)2i\sqrt{Dk^2\tau})^2\sqrt{(s-s_1)2i\sqrt{Dk^2\tau}}}
$$
In the time domain, the Green's function is essentially a spike. For $t$ of order $\tau$, it is just:
$$
\hat G = \frac1{(Dk^2)^{5/2}}\delta(t)
$$
The first scaling gives the rise to the maximum:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat G &= \int \frac{ds}{2\pi i}\frac1{(Dk^2+\tau s^2)^{5/2}}e^{st} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}}{(Dk^2)^{5/2}}\frac{(\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}t)^2J_2(\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}t)}3H(t) \\
\delta G_{nn}(t,k) &= (T \chi)D'^2\,k^4\,(\tau D k^2)^{1/2}\left(\frac\tau{Dk^2}\right)^{3/2}\frac{(\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}t)^2J_2(\sqrt{Dk^2/\tau}t)}3H(t)
\end{align}
$$
This is valid for $t$ of order $\sqrt{\tau/Dk^2}$.
The second scaling gives the slower decay of order $\tau$ modulated by a large frequency:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat G &= \int \frac1{((s-s_1-1/\tau)2i\sqrt{Dk^2\tau})^2\sqrt{(s-s_1)2i\sqrt{Dk^2\tau}}}e^{st}\frac{ds}{2\pi i} \\
&= \frac\tau{(2i\sqrt{Dk^2\tau})^{5/2}}\cos\left(\sqrt{\tau/Dk^2}t\right)e^{-t/\tau}\frac{(1+2t/\tau)F(\sqrt{t/\tau}-\sqrt{t/\tau})}{\sqrt\pi}H(t)
\end{align}
$$
with $F$ the Dawson function (courtesy of Wolfram Alpha).
The physical relevance of these different scalings depends on the domain of validity of your starting integral formula.
